# C# Contained Class Inherit From Base Class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have the following structure

```
public class mymainClass
{
  public class containedClass : would like to Inherit Class here (without doing it here)
  {properties {get;set;} 
}

public class mymainClass
{
  public class containedClass : InheritClass BUT DONT SPECIFY INTERNALLY
  {properties {get;set;} 
}
```

I would love to do this - but WE KNOW  IT CANT BE DONE.

```
public class mymainClass<T>
{
  public class containedClass : T
  {properties {get;set;} 
}
```

*How can I accomplish getting the contained class to inherit form something I specify in the container class construction ?*

**EDIT**
Right now I need to create these classes specifically for the fact that the internal class is specific, if I can write the whole thing generically I can pass in the specific item and simplify ..

So the internal Class ..

Perhaps I could do something like

```
public class mymainClass<T>
{
   public mymainClass<T>(){
   this.containedClass = T;
}
  public class containedClass : would like to Inherit Class here (without doing it here)
  {properties {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: why do want to do that? what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: you can make both classes generic i guess

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```cs
public class Main<T>
    where T: Main<T>.Nested
{
    public class Nested { }
}

public class Derived:Main<Derived.DerivedNested> {
    public class DerivedNested : Nested{ }
}
```

Or perhaps something like;

```cs
public class Main<T>
    where T: Main<T>.INested
{
    public interface INested { 
        void DefaultMethod() { ... }
    }
}
```

(this probably doesn't count as an "Answer", but is too complex for a comment...)

Comment: Please check out my edit essentially the internal class needs to be there and it needs to be Item : I am basically substituting properties - the framework I am using requires this structure and so I need to be able to do it this way to be generic.